# Attach the name of each dataframe as a column after looping over a list of dataframes in R

Tags: r, list, dataframe, spreadsheet

I created a list of dataframes. I need to loop over them, filter what I need and save as a single file.
However, I need to know from each file each values comes from.

Each dataframe has a name like Plastic Chair 1111, Wooden Chair 3950, Table 6909, etc... and are saved inside a list named "listed" that contains the following structure:

```
listed[1]

Material_ID  ABC  Key.Figure   W01  W02  W03
46548970     A    Actuals     1048  564  548
46548970     A    Forecasted  848   500  590 
18969856     A    Actuals     358   1500 900 
18969856     A    Forecasted  460   1602 1000

listed[2]

Material_ID  ABC  Key.Figure   W01  W02  W03
24564897     A    Actuals     1258  444  798
26548970     A    Forecasted  1345  500  850 
34879856     A    Actuals      985  1020 980 
15486856     A    Forecasted   846  1064 1100
```

What I would like to obtain is:

```
   Group name  Group Code Material_ID  ABC  Key.Figure   W01  W02  W03
   Plastic Chair   1111   46548970     A    Actuals     1048  564  548
   Plastic Chair   1111   18969856     A    Actuals     358   1500 900 
    Wooden Chair   3950   24564897     A    Actuals     1258  444  798
    Wooden Chair   3950   34879856     A    Actuals      985  1020 980
```

Is it possible to create these two columns on the left by using the dataframes name?

Thank you very much for the help!

Here is my code if you need to better understand the situation.

```
library(openxlsx)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

# read the data
filename = 'Dataset.xlsx'
wb <- loadWorkbook(filename)

# get a list of the spreadshits in the excel file
sheetNames <- sheets(wb)
sheetNames <- make_names(sheetNames)

# create an empty list
listed <- list()

# assign which spreadshit as a dataframe inside a list
for(i in 1:length(sheetNames))
{
  listed[[i]] <- assign(sheetNames[i],readWorkbook(wb,sheet = i))
  print(paste0("read the ", i," file")) # here it says what it's doing
}

# remove variable Sales.Org.ID
map(listed, ~ (.x %>% select(-Sales.Org.ID)))

# filter the dataframes to only show rows with Key.Figure = "Actual Totals"
list_actuals <- lapply(listed, function(x) x %>%
                         filter( Key.Figure == "Actual Totals"),
  )

# put the result in a single dataframe  
result_actuals = do.call(rbind,list_actuals)
```

Comment: Have you looked at `purrr::map_dfr` which works for a list of named dataframes appending the dataframe name using the `.id` argument?

Comment: Very difficult to provide an answer to this without a minimal reproducible example.  I will note that you can now put dataframes in the columns of a bigger dataframe with list columns.  If you had a column with the names of your dataframes, you can then add a column called `data` containing each dataframe and then mutate a function to do the filtering, and then do an `rbind` on the mutated column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think simplifying the code a little would help. For example, don't change the sheet names with `make_names` first, then iterate over sheet numbers to import. Instead, use the unaltered sheet names until after importing the data and change the names later if desired. Also instead of `lapply` followed by rbind, try `map_df`. It is not quite as specialized as the `purrr::mapdfr` suggested in the comments but it is a bit easier to see what is happening. In the example code below I used a `mutate` inside the `map_df` to insert the name into each data frame before `map_df` combines them.

```
library(openxlsx)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

# read the data
filename = 'Dataset.xlsx'
wb <- loadWorkbook(filename)

wb %>%
    sheets() %>%

    # read all of the sheets, put the sheet name in a new column
    map_df(~readWorkbook(wb, sheet = .x) %>% mutate(group_name = .x)) %>%
    
    # remove variable Sales.Org.ID
    select(-Sales.Org.ID) %>%

    # filter the dataframes to only show rows with Key.Figure = "Actual Totals"
    filter( Key.Figure == "Actual Totals") %>%

    # if you still want to change the names taken from the sheet names
    mutate(group_name = make_name(group_name))
```

Comment: thanks a lot for all the tips and help. I tried to used your code, but I obtain an error: <error/dplyr:::mutate_error>
Problem with `mutate()` input `group_name`.
x Objekt '.x' nicht gefunden
i Input `group_name` is `.x`.

Comment: looks like there was an extra paren after `readWorkbook(...)`. I edited the answer to fix it

Comment: I had already seen the extra parenthesis and corrected it. That's not what is causing my error...

Comment: It's hard to confirm without the actual data on hand (or code that can create a reproducible example of the error) but I do have few more suggestions for things to check based on what I can see or guess. The `~` could be missing from the beginning of the code inside the  `map()` step.  The example data shown doesn't have a column called "Sales.Org.ID". Lastly, the `make_names()` function isn't defined here, perhaps it should be `make.names()` instead?

Comment: You were right! There was a missing "s" in the name of the function make_name. Thank you so much for all the help! I had reached the result as well, but your solution is much cleaner and better executed, which help me to learn as well. Thank you also for the time in figuring out the problems...